# DB error after Matrix update

Tags: matrix, pixelandtonic

Have just updated **Matrix to 2.5.6**.

When I go to **Add-ons > Fieldtypes > Matrix** to trigger the update script I get this error.

> A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1060
>
> Duplicate column name 'var_id'
>
> ALTER TABLE exp_matrix_cols ADD var_id INT(6) UNSIGNED AFTER field_id,
>   ADD INDEX (var_id)
>
> Filename: third_party/matrix/ft.matrix.php
>
> Line Number: 496

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly needs to be run? Where is the version number supposed to be set? Inside of the exp_matrix_data table?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the columns in exp_matrix_data table in the database.

- Does it have a field var_id? If no, then the version you should set is 2.2.
- If yes, does it have a field is_draft? If no, then the version you should set is 2.3
- If yes, then the version you should set is 2.5.6

Now, set the version number we determined in the previous three steps for the Matrix field in the exp_fieldtypes table and go visit the Add-ons -> Fieldtypes -> Matrix page and hit submit.

Everything should be all working now.